# touch(): Unable to create file

Tags: php

in my localhost i get touch(): Unable to create file error in php 
my config code is

```
$config = array(
    'accountid' => 'sushil-pc\liberty-sales',
    'mediadb' => '../../.cm4all/mediadb/',
    'listingkey' => 'IFHJK4JHDYAE5X5HJTVQ',
    'hosting-backend-server' => 'localhost:8080',
    'maxiprocfilesize' => '10000000',
    'maxiprocimagesize' => '5000'
);
```

its in my local system.Can anybody help?i m stuck for whole day,should i change anything??Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the full error message? For all we know, it's `touch: I need an adult!`

Comment: Have you checked the permissions in the directory where you want to create the file?

Comment: the folder has full access to read write

Comment: the full error message is    Warning: touch(): Unable to create file ./../.cm4all/.cache/.unavailable because No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\swissmantra\.cm4all\include\BengProxy.php on line 381

Comment: From the error you are at `D:\xampp\htdocs\swissmantra\.cm4all\include\BengProxy.php` and the relative path you're providing is `./../.cm4all/.cache/` which means you're trying to create a file at `D:\xampp\htdocs\swissmantra\.cm4all\.cm4all\.cache`... is that the correct full path or are you missing an additional `../`?

Comment: no the full path is D:\xamp\htdocs\swissmantra\.cm4all\.cache

Answer (score 8):

In config.php

Replace following line

> $config['sess_save_path'] = 'application/session/';

with

> $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'session/';