# php artisan tinker error , how can fix this error ? touch():

Tags: php, laravel, windows, apache, xampp

> ErrorException touch(): Unable to create file
> C:\xampp\htdocs\solisadeqi.com\vendor\psy\psysh\srcC:/Users///AppData/Roaming/PsySH/psysh_history
> because No such file or directory at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\solisadeqi.com\vendor\psy\psysh\src\ConfigPaths.php:250

```
246|         if (!self::ensureDir(\dirname($file))) {
247|             return false;
248|         }
249| 
> 250|         \touch(__DIR__.$file); 
251|
252|         return $file;
253|     }
254| }
```

1

> C:\xampp\htdocs\solisadeqi.com\vendor\psy\psysh\src\ConfigPaths.php:250
> touch("C:\xampp\htdocs\solisadeqi.com\vendor\psy\psysh\srcC:/Users///AppData/Roaming/PsySH/psysh_history")

2

> C:\xampp\htdocs\solisadeqi.com\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Configuration.php:594
> Psy\ConfigPaths::touchFileWithMkdir("C:/Users///AppData/Roaming/PsySH/psysh_history")

---

how can i change this path: C:/Users///AppData/Roaming/PsySH/psysh_history ?

I don't know what '///' means ?!

I have 3 users on my windows.
I run laravel on xampp(apache).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [touch(): Unable to create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654747/touch-unable-to-create-file)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, try organizing your post a little better. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help